# Site doesn't work on Safari but loads fine on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, safari, ios

I'm trying to load [www.zhongwen.com](http://www.zhongwen.com) on Safari on the iPad on iOS 14 (but I encounter the same issue on Safari for Mac). The site loads fine, but clicking on any Chinese character doesn't load the correct elements for that character (it appears as a broken image). You can compare the results on Chrome/Firefox and notice that Safari doesn't load properly.

Interestingly, the site loads fine on Safari for iPad on iOS 6. I'm not sure what's different between Safari on iOS 6 and iOS 14, but hopefully that helps someone diagnose the issue. I noticed that there are Experimental settings for Safari but not sure what any mean and afraid to change anything.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This is usually an issue involving the development of the website.  iOS 6 Safari is vastly different than iOS 13 or 14 Safari and whatever responsive design tweaks the developer used for Safari back then may no longer be applicable today.  This is something the developer needs to address.

Comment: I do find it interesting (odd perhaps) that this site is using an XML namespace from Facebook.com that's 1) not using https and 2) is immediately redirected to https://ogp.me (another facebook domain).